# Discover WCF services in Solution

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with a WCF service which works fine. I have added a small console app in the solution which needs to have a Service reference to the service in the same solution.
It discovers the service but obviously can't connect to it as the service is not running.
How in Visual Studio 2010 I can have the service running in the solution and at the same time add a service reference in the same solution?

Comment: Make sure you have a WCF Service Library project and not WCF Service Application project for the WCF service. I had a similar problem, and this helped for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the Client Application is in the same solution as the WCF Service project, r-click the client application and choose "Add Service Reference".

A dialogue is displayed allowing you to select your Service by clicking the button in the top right labelled "Discover".

Assuming the binding is correctly set and available for the WCF Service (via an app.config file or similar) the IDE will automatically host the service for you. - note, the app.config should be located within the WCF Service project unless there is a designated host already available in another project within the solution.

If there are any issues hosting the service, a new dialogue will appear, with the right hand column for your service endpoints saying "Error".  Clicking the errored line will explain why there is an issue and hopefully help you to resolve it.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. When clicking Discover, it finds the service. However when I click OK then is trying to connect to the service which is obviously not running.

Comment: @koumides - You'll need to explain more.  So you can discover the service?  Does it let you see the exposed service contract and operations?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Ok. As soon as I click Discover, I can see the service. Then I need to click OK to close the "Add Service Reference" Window. At that time it is trying to connect to the service but the Service obviously is not running.

Comment: @koumides - why is it "obviously not running"?  You are able to discover the service because it is running.  Is that the confusion?  The reason it works is because Visual Studio automatically hosts your service for you when you click discover - it finds the services and creates a temporary host.  To see this in action, set your service library as the startup project and click run - VS will start 2 applications for you, 1 to host your service, the second is an interface allowing you to call methods on the service. That make sense?

Comment: Also note, these applications VS runs for you, are only available inside the IDE.  If you need the services hosted outside of a debug environment, you will need to provide your own hosts.

Comment: Apologies. It is all sorted now. I thought the service was working fine but I did make a change just before creating the reference which broke it.

Comment: @Smudge202 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1836/discussion-between-koumides-and-smudge202)

Comment: In my case I had my service binding set as net.tcp, but I had not changed the base address to start with "net.tcp".  Running the service from the IDE and clicking on the Error row as described in this answer showed me the exact problem.  After fixing it I was able to Add Service Reference/Discover my service project.

Answer (score 2):

> Not true. WCF Service projects can self host themselves within the IDE for the purpose of adding service references

Yes, if the project with service is the main project of the solution, but if we want to start a client app from the same solution we need to set main project to client app and as result wcf app won't start by itself, so we need helper class that hosts wcf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a console application that self-hosts the WCF project in the same solution, use "Add Reference" (instead of "Add Service Reference") and under Solution you will find the Service in your Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer, and select Unload project

Right-click the project again (this time the node will end in (unavailable) ) and choose Edit xxxxx.csproj

In the first  section, add the following line:
{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

Save and close the file
Reload the project by right-clicking it again and choose Reload.
 You should then be able to use the "Discover services in solution" functionality

Run the application and attach the debugger to wcfsvchost.exe

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx

You need to host your service. Create a class that will do it in the same solution

Comment: Not true.  WCF Service projects can self host themselves within the IDE for the purpose of adding service references

Comment: @smudge, yes but that's only for providing service metadata, you would also need to start a real host to run the actual service, you could do this by hitting F5 on the project/website that hosts the service, that will get it running.

Comment: @Chris, I partially agree, you do not require a designated host project in the solution in order to run the service.  With a sufficient app.config provided you can achieve this by starting the WCF Service Library itself - the IDE will again self-host the service, and provide the test client for you.  (i.e. Create a solution, add a single project - WCF Service Library - hit run)

Comment: @Chris Probably not necessary, but as better proof, follow the previous steps of starting a standalone WCF Service Library, then open a second VS instance with a console app. Choose "Add Service Reference" and enter the URL displayed in the WCFHost Dialogue (Minimized to System Tray by default).  So long as you are on the same machine, you can add references and run a second application against the self-hosted service.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Chris

I gave my advice thinking about one VS instance. I think 2 VS instance it is not comfortable.