# WCF allow services to be discovered

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I just can't find anything relating to this.

I have 4 WCF services within the same project, in order for new projects to link to the services, I need to manually enter all 4 the end points in "add service reference":

1. https://myurl.com/Services/Test1.svc
2. https://myurl.com/Services/Test2.svc
3. https://myurl.com/Services/Test3.svc
4. https://myurl.com/Services/Test4.svc

What I'd really like to do is use a single URL (maybe something like https://myurl.com/Services/), which when entered into the address of the "add service reference" dialog, will discover the 4 services and list them just like it does when you click the "discover" button when adding service references to a project in the same solution.

The only thing I've found is [WCF Discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) but that's for when you're broadcasting on a subnet and that's not what I'm trying to do.

Edit: This isn't a duplicate of the proposed question.  That OP is having issues getting their services discovered correctly within the same solution which I'm having no trouble with.  I'd like to get the same list of services from an outside solution like you get when you're in a project that's part of the same solution as the services.  Trust this clarifies sufficiently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discover WCF services in Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828587/discover-wcf-services-in-solution)

Comment: Is this any use - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31285/WS-Discovery-for-WCF?

Comment: if your issue is only add reference to many service url, you can implement all interfaces in one only service, then all your operations (Test1, Test2 and so on) will be grouped in the same service. Discovery is more used when don't know exactly where the service is running.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for that, definitely some good reading.  The only problem is that it only works AFTER you've already built the client.  I'm looking for a way to discover the services on the server during the initial development of the client

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yeah, I've been reading up on combining services, though I don't want to simply combine services for the sake of combining them since they're very different from one another.  But I will be looking seriously at it.